# wordpress theme layout abnormally when i logout from dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I am making a site width wordpress and theme [Constructo](http://themeforest.net/item/constructo-wp-construction-business-theme/9835983). The plugins are Contact Form 7, Revolution Slider,WPBakery Visual Composer, ssh sftp updater support.

when i login as administrator, the site looks normal, but when i logout, the layout is chaotic. I found that the page code generate uncompletely in the logout state. I wonder if it is related with the authority of the server. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I think it is due to some specific css..Just check the source code of the page in both the cases, hopefully you will get the issue

Comment: not just css, the html tag is different between two states.

Comment: Check if the theme or a plugin use settings to make things visible to specific user roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Sunil Chaudhary and @mparryy , i find the answer. I have set a coming soon page sometime, it causes the result.